# Hide query parameters in RewriteRule

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^farm-products/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ products.php?$1&page=$2&what=$3&t=$4&cat=$5
```

The user sees:

```
http://www.example.com/farm-products/agencies/56/b/88/32458
```

Is it possible to hide from the URL the query parameters?

I want to show only:

```
http://www.example.com/farm-products/agencies/
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your CMS that you are using.

However, most likely the answer is that you cannot do that easily at least. The CMS would need to be modified to do the category / product lookups using the their titles instead of identifiers. This might take quite some effort.

You need to discuss this issue with your CMS developer.